# Converting time from character to numeric using proc sql - sas

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm facing problem in calculating No.of hours since time is in character format.

```
Booked_from($)   booked_to($)
======================================
07:00            18:00
08:00            17:00
```

I want the difference between these two fields and create a new field "Hours".

My Code:

```
booked_Hours=intck(minutes,attendee.booked_to,attendee.booked_from)
```

But it is giving an error

Comment: The 1st parameter for intck function needs to be in quotes. Please refer to the link to know how intck function is used to calculate hour, minutes etc. : http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/INTCK_function_examples

Comment: That's not the only problem, the time values are in character, so you need to use `input` to convert them: `input(attendee.booked_from,time5.)`. Also, it seems strange that you'd call the field 'hours' when it'll calculate minutes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code illustrates the correct way to use `intck` and convert characters to numeric using an informat:

```
data _NULL_;
  input Booked_from $  booked_to $;
  minutes=intck('minutes',input(booked_from,time5.),input(booked_to,time5.));
  hours=intck('hours',input(booked_from,time5.),input(booked_to,time5.));
  put _all_;
  datalines;
  07:00            18:00
  08:00            17:00
  ;
run;
```

As I mentioned in my comment, if you want 'hours' then you need to specify an interval type of 'hours', not minutes.

Also, I've reversed the order of the second and third arguments, as the original method was giving a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, I have one more point to add. You have to use conditional statements to calculate difference if Booked_from is 23:30 and Booked_to is 1:00. In this case you will get diffrence values in minus.

Below code will help you resolve this

```
data mins;
    set <your dataset>;
    attrib fromtime totime format=time5.;

    fromtime=input(booked_from,time5.);
    totime=input(booked_to,time5.);

    if(totime < fromtime) then do;
        min=intck('minutes',fromtime,'24:00't)+intck('minutes','00:00't,totime);
    end;
    else do;
        min=intck('minutes',fromtime,totime);
    end;
run;
```